# How can I open vim and automatically write a date to the file?

Tags: vim

If I run this in vim `:r !date`, it will read from the `date` command

How do I run this within the `-c` option for vim?

I've tried `vim -c ":r !date" myfile.txt` but I get

```
`bash: !date": event not found`
```

I've tried `vim -c "r !date" myfile.txt` but I get

```
`bash: !date": event not found`
```

I've tried `vim -c ":r date" myfile.txt` but I get

```
Error detected while processing command line:
E484: Can't open file date
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `!` is a special character in bash, and should be escaped. Otherwise use single quotes. Some alternatives:

```
vim -c 'r!date'
vim -c r\!date
vim +'r!date'
vim +r\!date
```

Note that all of these will leave a line after the date. If you want to start the file with one line only, this line being the date, you could use:

```
vim +.\!date
vim +'.!date'
```

Or the `-c` variant, of course.

```
vim -c '.!date'
```

To add the date at the end of the file:

```
vim +'$r!date' file
vim -c '$r!date' file
```

To add an extra newline before the date, you could just add an empty bash echo:

```
vim +'$r! echo ; date' file
```

A more “native” Vim approach could be achieved by adding an extra command before the read, to perform a normal mode sequence 'Go' (last line then newline after cursor). In this case the range at the read command is not necessary since the cursor will be at the correct position already:

```
vim +'normal Go' +'r!date' file
```

Comment: `vim -c 'r!date' todo.txt` totally worked! do you know how to add the date at the end of the file?

Comment: wow, how do you even search the docs for that? thanks sidyll! do you know how to add a carriage return or newline before the `!date`?

Comment: @theptrk Search for the `:r!` command. It accepts a range so the $ there represents last line. About adding the extra space, I’ll update the answer again. More space to format properly... :)

Comment: How could I arrange the format YEAR-MONTH-DAY? Would it be possible to create a file with that name? (with a markdown or txt format, for instance).

Comment: @nilon just interpolate a command as the name `vim +.\!date $(date +%F).md`.

Comment: Could it be possible to insert that file name and/or format date as title or first line?

Comment: @nilon yes, of course. Just pass the formatting argument to the first call. Sorry, do you know some Unix basics? I do recommending checking out the man pages for these programs.

Comment: I was trying to search through the vim help. But that pointer seems great. You made me think. Perhaps I could start with `man man`. Yes? I've tried to use the same argument but can't figure where to cut and paste. I've got nothing but errors.

Comment: `vim +'.!date +\%F' $(date +%F).md` should do it. You need to escape the first `%` otherwise vim understands it as a special char. The second date call is expanded in bash.